# Will a cable HDMI to M1-DA work?

Tags: video, hdmi, dvi, cable, projector

My laptop (Dell XPS l502x) has only HDMI. And a couple of days ago I bought an used projector, without cables. It was said it accept DVI, so before it arrive I bought an HDMI to DVI cable, but when it came here I noticed that it was not DVI but M1-DA(P&D) instead (which is visually similar).

So now I need an adpter from HMDI or DVI to M1-DA (I am thinking of buying [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cables-To-Go-Female-Adapter/dp/B002CZQ4SI/ref=pd_cp_ce_1)). But after that I remember that to  connect my laptop to VGA I have a converter, not adapter, cause it is digital to analogue signal. Will it be the same with the M1-DA

Comment: I see no reason this wouldn't work.  The difference between your past experiences is that VGA isn't a digital signal but an analog signal.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just asked cause I was not sure if M1-DA was digital or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it will be helpful for anyone else, yes it works.

I was just not sure whether M1-DA is digital or not, cause I found some people saying that this  kind of adapters do not work just like I saw some dumb people complaining about HDMI to VGA cables which don't work.

But I I bought one anyway to see (the link in the question) and it works perfectly.